# Mocking Spring's jdbc KeyHolder using Mockito

Tags: java, spring, mockito

I need your help in solving one issue. I have such method in my DAO class that saves Role:

```
@Repository(value="jdbcRoleDAO")
@Transactional(propagation=Propagation.SUPPORTS, readOnly=true, rollbackFor=Exception.class)
public class JdbcRoleDAO implements RoleDAO {

    @Autowired
    private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

    @Autowired
    private DBLogger<Role> dbLogger;

    /**
     * @throws DublicateEntryException if object with specified unique for application field already 
     *              exists in DB.
     */
    @CacheEvict(value = "roles", allEntries = true)
    @Transactional(propagation=Propagation.REQUIRED, readOnly=false, rollbackFor=Exception.class)
    @Override
    public Role save(final Role role) {

        if (this.getRoleByName(role.getName()) != null) {
            throw new DublicateEntryException("Record with specified role name already exists in application.");
        }

        KeyHolder keyHolder = new GeneratedKeyHolder();
        jdbcTemplate.update(new PreparedStatementCreator() {

            @Override
            public PreparedStatement createPreparedStatement(Connection connection)
                    throws SQLException {

                PreparedStatement ps = connection.prepareStatement(SQL_INSERT_ROLE, new String[]{"ID"});

                ps.setString(1, role.getName());
                ps.setString(2, role.getDesription());
                ps.setObject(3, (role.getParentRole()!=null)?role.getParentRole().getId():null);
                ps.setString(4, role.getPrivilege().toString());

                return ps;
            }
        }, keyHolder);

        Long key = (Long) keyHolder.getKey();
        if (key != null) {
            role.setId(key);
        } else {
            role.setId(-1);
        }

        // Add information about operation to log table
        dbLogger.logBasicOperation(role, OperationName.CREATE);

        return role;
    }
...
}
```

And I want to write unit test for this method using Mockito. For now it looks like:

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class JdbcRoleDAOTest {

    private static final long TEST_ROLE_ID = 1L;
    private static final int TEST_ROLE_VERSION = 7;

    @Mock
    private DBLogger<Role> dbLogger;

    @Mock
    private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

    @InjectMocks
    private JdbcRoleDAO roleDAO;

    /**
     * test role that is used in all methods.
     */
    private Role role;

    @Before
    public void setUp(){
        // Create a test role object
        role = new Role();
        role.setId(TEST_ROLE_ID);
        role.setName("TEST");
        role.setDesription("Test role");
        role.setPrivilege(Privilege.DEFAULT);
        role.setVersion(TEST_ROLE_VERSION);

        // Return correct version of the object
        Mockito.when(jdbcTemplate.queryForInt(JdbcRoleDAO.SQL_GET_VERSION, TEST_ROLE_ID))
            .thenReturn(TEST_ROLE_VERSION);
    }

    @Test
    public void testSave() {
        Assert.assertNotNull(role);

        roleDAO.save(role);

        InOrder inOrder = Mockito.inOrder(jdbcTemplate, dbLogger);

        // Verify execution of the conditions.
        inOrder.verify(jdbcTemplate, Mockito.times(1)).update(Mockito.any(PreparedStatementCreator.class), 
                Mockito.any(KeyHolder.class));

        inOrder.verify(dbLogger, Mockito.times(1)).logBasicOperation(role, OperationName.CREATE);

        /* 
         * Expected -1 because I can't mock KeyHolder and should be returned -1 value (because 
         * KeyHolder will return null instead of key)
         */ 
        Assert.assertEquals("Generated id is wrong!", -1, role.getId());
    }
…
}
```

The problem is in that I want to mock somehow KeyHolder but I don’t know how better to do this. As you see, now KeyHolder instance is created in the save method and that’s is a main difficulty. I thought about injecting KeyHolder using Spring with scope “prototype” but as I understand this can cause problems when few users will concurrently try to save new Roles. Also I tried to do something like this:

```
Mockito.when(jdbcTemplate.update(Mockito.any(PreparedStatementCreator.class), 
                Mockito.any(KeyHolder.class)))
                .thenAnswer(new Answer<Void>() {

                    @Override
                    public Void answer(InvocationOnMock invocation)
                            throws Throwable {

                        Object[] arguments = invocation.getArguments();
                        for (int i=0; i<arguments.length; i++) {
                            if (arguments[i] instanceof KeyHolder) {
                                KeyHolder keyHolder = (KeyHolder) arguments[i];

                                KeyHolder spyKeyHolder = Mockito.spy(keyHolder);
                                Mockito.when(spyKeyHolder.getKey()).thenReturn(TEST_GENERATED_ID);
                                Mockito.doReturn(TEST_GENERATED_ID).when(spyKeyHolder).getKey();
                            }
                        }

                        return null;
                    }
                });
```

But this doesn’t work. 
May be someone can give me an advice how it is possible to mock (or spy) KeyHolder not moving it outside from save method? Is there some features in Mockito that can make this possible? Or it is impossible?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could create the following interface:

```
public interface KeyHolderFactory {
     KeyHolder newKeyHolder();
}
```

Then add a `KeyHolderFactory` field inside your `JdbcRoleDAO`, to be filled through dependency injection in production, and manually with a mock while testing. The production implementation is straightforward, and you can use a single instance of it (singleton):

```
public class GeneratedKeyHolderFactory implements KeyHolderFactory {
     public KeyHolder newKeyHolder() {
         return new GeneratedKeyHolder();
     }
}
```

Inside the method you will have

```
...
KeyHolder keyHolder = factory.newKeyHolder();
...
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can switch to [PowerMock](http://code.google.com/p/powermock/) you can mock constructors too and then you can mock the GeneratedKeyHolder constructor to return a mock KeyHolder